# Why are there stars when I throw a pokeball?

Tags: pokemon-third-generation

It is not always happening, Sometimes when I throw a pokeball and successfully catch that pokemon, It has little stars showing, What is the meaning of that?

The version I am playing is Emerald, Ruby, and Sapphire.

Comment: In Pokemon Crystal, Pokemon Black? Which edition?

Comment: Sorry i forgot to add, I edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That means you've probably captured a Shiny Pokemon!

Shiny Pokémon in the games may differ in color from their normal counterparts either very little or very much. Usually the former is the case, with some Pokémon, such as Glaceon or Pichu, having their Shiny form be only a few shades lighter or darker in color, although a majority of the Pokémon that exhibit this are not in their final form of evolution. However, many Pokémon will have a spectacular difference between their normal and Shiny variations; even extremely common Pokémon like Caterpie show a dramatic difference. An evolutionary line is not necessarily guaranteed to have similar alternate colorations, even if their standard colorations remain consistent; both Ponyta and Rapidash have orange flames, but an alternate colored Ponyta has blue flames, while an alternate colored Rapidash has gray flames (with this being the opposite in Generation II). The opposite can also be true, as in the case of Skitty and Delcatty.

Shiny Pokemon have a very low chance of appearing though, so you'll have to be VERY lucky. When you see a shiny pokemon, it will 'sparkle' when it's out of the pokeball and it has a different colour.

When Shiny Pokemon appear on the battlefield, those stars and sparkles accompany him. You can check it yourself by calling out your caught Pokemon to the battlefield.

Comment: I am wondering.. Is this the effect you've seen? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qmOAstq7c8w